# What's the Tkinter equivalent of the css "overflow scroll"?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, scrollbar

I have a window in Tkinter that includes a bunch of labels. My problem is that if there are more labels than the size of the window, it wont display and i cant scroll either. The scroll bar is there but doesn't function.

How do i properly implement a scrollbar to see all my labels?

```
def __init__(self, root):
        top = Toplevel()
        self.root = root
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(top)
        scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )
        for text in file_list:
            link = Tkinter.Label(top, text=text, foreground="#0000ff", cursor="hand1")
            link.bind("<1>", lambda event, text=text: \
                        click_link(self, event, text))
            link.pack()
```

I tried using a canvas. I took an example from another post and input my labels. Same results as before. The Scrollbar is there, but not functional.

```
root=Tk()
global jack
jack = Toplevel()
frame=Frame(root,width=300,height=300)
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='#FFFFFF',width=300,height=300,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))
hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(width=300,height=300)
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
for text in folder_sel:
    link = Tkinter.Label(jack, text=text, foreground="#0000ff", cursor="hand1")
    link.bind("<1>", lambda event, text=text: \
                new_list(self, event, text))
    link.pack() 
for text in file_list:
    link = Tkinter.Label(canvas, text=text, foreground="#0000ff", cursor="hand1")
    link.bind("<1>", lambda event, text=text: \
                click_link(self, event, text))
    link.pack()
```

Comment: Create the labels on a `Canvas` and bind the scrollbar to it.

Comment: I just edited my post. Tried using a canvas, still cant get a grasp on doing it properly. Thanks for the step in the right direction.